# How to check two rows in normalized table as we do in flat table

Tags: sql, database-normalization

**Flat Table Structure**

```
DudeTable
ID Dude NextDoorDude
1  Jim  Nick
2  Mike Mike
```

so if I write a query to compare them, I'd use
`SELECT count(*) FROM DudeTable WHERE Dude = NextDoorDude`

**Normalized Form**

```
DudeTable
ID DudeType Name
1  person   Jim
1  neighbor Nick
2  person   Mike
2  neighbor Mike
```

How do I write a query to compare two rows and get the similar result as I did for flat table?

This could be a simple scenario but I have no idea... Googling didn't help me... Hope someone here would shed some light

Comment: Nothing in this post involves database normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select id
from dudetable t
group by id
having max(case when dudetype = 'person' then name end) = max(case when dudetype = 'neighbor' then name);
```

Another method uses `join`:

```
select dp.id, dp.name
from dudetable dp join
     dudetable dn
     on dp.id = dn.id and
        dp.dudetype = 'person' and
        dn.dudetype = 'neighbor' and
        dp.name = dn.name
```